# ES6 yield multiple generators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6 yield and generator function allow to await once function will execute. But I want to await multiple generators.
Here the code:

```
files.forEach(function* (file) {
    const uploadedFile = yield call([service, service.upload], file, config)
}
```

`call` is [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html) effect

> To express the Saga logic we yield plain JavaScript Objects from the Generator. We call those Objects Effects

I want to fire all uploads in one time, without waiting before previous finished and wait once all files got uploaded, is it possible with `yield`?

Comment: This depends on what `call` is, this needs explanation. If you're using `co` or something, you can use `Promise.all`. You can't do that with yieldable itself, just because of generators' nature. They are 'paused' with `yield`.

Comment: @estus `call` is effect creator function from redux-saga lib https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Comment: Then the question should mention it, since this solely depends on where this generator comes from. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What is the result of `call(...)`? If it is a promise, the answer is applicable. If it's not, it's not.

Comment: @estus added it to the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I was looking for was actually this:

```
// correct, effects will get executed in parallel
const [users, repos]  = yield [
  call(fetch, '/users'),
  call(fetch, '/repos')
]
```

`call` here is just returning promise

> When we yield an array of effects, the generator is blocked until all the effects are resolved or as soon as one is rejected (just like how Promise.all behaves).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise.all() instead

**EXAMPLE:**

If you want to fire all uploads and regain control of the code after they all finished you can use async/await interface:

```
function uploadALL(files){
  const uploadedFilesPromises = files.map( file => {
    return call([service, service.upload], file 
  })        
  }
  return Promise.all(uploadedFilesPromises);
} 

// samples of using this function:
uploadALL(files).then((uploadedFiles)=> { ....  })
// or in async function you can use await:
const uploadedFiles = await uploadAll(files)
```

Your "call" method should return a Promise object, otherwise you have to wrap it into Promise.

Comment: You could maybe write it out based on the Asker's sample code.

Comment: @AlexeyKuznetsov how it will work if not using `async/await` just generators?

Comment: @Grievoushead without async/await you just should use my first sample of using, uploadALL returns Promise anyway and it doesn't need to be async (I have edited my example of code). You don't need generators at all here, just Promises.

Comment: @AlexeyKuznetsov The problem here is that you assume here that generators are promise-based (like co). Which is not the case.

Comment: @estus I think they are according to redux-saga docs: Sagas can yield Effects in multiple forms. The simplest way is to yield a Promise. But I was aware with solution via Promise.all just curious if there are some ways with generators